# String replace double quotes & slash

Tags: json, string

I'm trying JSON Parser and in the JSON I've `\"` (for like `<tag style=\"color: #fff;\"...`)
If I can replace `\"` with `\\"` the parser works fine (like in this - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092v4IAA)

> Input {"name":"Surya\".\""}  like name = Surya"."
>
> Output {"name":"Surya\".\""}

```
String input = '{"name":"Surya\".\""}';

System.debug( input );
//String output = input.replace('\"', '\\\"');
String output = input.replaceAll('\\\"', '\\\\\"');
System.debug( output );
```

I tried with replace & replaceAll.
Please advice me. Thanks.

Comment: what is not working that is not clear from your question.

Comment: Please check the Input & Output and I'm trying few things which are not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the value strings in your JSON is encoded, the simplest and most reliable way to decode is to use a deserialize call:

```
System.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped('"Surya\\".\\""'));
```

For your example something like:

```
String input = '{"name":"Surya\".\""}';
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(input);

String encodedNameValue = (String) m.get('name');
String nameValue = (String) JSON.deserializeUntyped(encodedNameValue);
```